# which video players do not require file format conversion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I want to use a video player using html 5 and flash. Now the video player will be displayed on  online exams and teachers will simply upload video files. I have basic extension validation where the teacher has to choose either `.mp4, .ogg, .wav or .flv.`.

Now I want the video player to work on all major browsers and I do not want users to mess about converting formats. I want a video player which works for the above formats stright away on all browsers without any problems or conversions needed.

Could somebody recommend a video player which can do this? I tried to use jwplayer but realised after uploading an .mp4 file that it would not display the video until I convert the video. I don't want teachers or students who have no knowledge or no access rights to be able to do this so that is why I want a different video player which just works straight away with ease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not all major browsers support all formats.. it's beyond the developer of the players.

The best solution would be to have a server side video converter that converts uploaded videos to 3 formats and displays the links in an html5 video player like [projekktor](http://www.projekktor.com/).

Comment: Do you know what I realised with my jwplayer6, it works when I tested it on ipad but does not work on my laptop. What certain features could cause this on my laptop to not work? Am I missing certain things possibly? it is just that the video is playing but not being displayed on my laptop. Here is link [link](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/previewvideo.php?filename=sample_mpeg4_5.mp4). Does it work on your computer because I am just seeing a black screen on video player

Comment: mobile safari must support mp4 video. It ultimately depends on the ability of the browser. most browsers support .ogg but not all.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [video.js](http://videojs.com) or [mediaelement](http://mediaelementjs.com).

With mediaelement you get an ok coverage of browsers with a single format (via Flash/Silverlight fallbacks), but you can get a wide range of browsers (just oldIE needs flash) playing video natively with both h264 and webm versions of your content. See the chart on the [mediaelement homepage](http://mediaelementjs.com/#devices) for the breakdown.

Ideally you'd take the user's upload and convert it to the necessary formats for them.

Comment: I'd also recommend MediaElementJs. It also falls back to Flash if the browser supports HTML5 video but not the file format presented. For example if you provide it with a MP4 file, which Firefox doesn't support, Flash will be used.